# What would be the proper lighting technique for my scene

Tags: lighting

[image: Spaceship shield glow]I have created a scene in which a spaceship is under gunnery fire from laser bolts. The ship is surrounded by an energy shield which glows when the laser bolts impact it. The bolts are a particle systems. On eevee 2.81 render, the point light illuminated the glowing shield but the ship itself is quite dark. In fact, the shields glow too bright. What would be my next method to properly light up this scene? One which would brighten up the ship and shields without blowing out the shield glow? Thanks

OK I have answered my own question it would appear. I deleted the point light and added an area light instead and the details of the ship show up as in my 3rd image. I will play with the bloom settings in order to get the impacts bloom under control. All good here. Question can be closed.

Danny

[image: Spaceship]

[image: Solved]

Comment: For such a purely visual question, without attaching an image we’re (literally) shooting in the dark.

I would say try turning the shield glow off, illuminating the ship first, then bring the shields back incrementally.

John

Comment: The way this is currently phrased invites opinion based answers. We don't even know what render engine you are using, which seems crucial to answer a lighting technique

Comment: Hi everyone, I have added the render engine and an image. As for the description of the issue, for me it is as clear as my comprehension of the english language can allow me, so if this is still not clear, then my english isn't at the standard I think it is.

Comment: I have added 2 images which I hope it will help with clarifying my question. The shield glows only on impact and this lighting is a point light set at 500 W. I played with the intensity and it gets worst the brighter I turn on the light. I tried bringing in the light but the glow gets worst as well. Am looking to get the ship bright enough so it's details are visible. I hope this clarifies the question.